# Routing traffic from internal network through VPN

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I need your help regarding a network configuration between different machines.

I have 6 Ubuntu servers which have two NICs, eth0 + eth1. eth0 has a public IP which connects to the internet through the provider gateway. eth1 is connected to a switch along with the rest of the servers and the interfaces are bridged together to form veths. With the current configuration the veths on each server communicate directly. After having a need to add two more servers, it was impossible for the hosting company to add them to the switch along with the others. So they made the **same** configuration with the NICs but this time the eth1 interfaces were connected with a crossover cable.

My question: Is it possible to route traffic from the secondary interfaces using either the public IP of eth0 on all machines, or using a VPN connection? I tried connecting one of the first six with one from the new servers using VPN and I had successful connectivity.

What I tried so far:

- Route traffic to the veth network using the tunnel interface

  ```
  route add -net <veth_network> netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev tun0
  ```

without luck

Is there an alternative?

Comment: What interfaces are you bridging? Sounds like you are saying that each server is bridging traffic between `eth0` and `eth1`. But doing that would make no sense and likely break things, so I assume you meant something else.

Comment: agree with @kasperd  The question is not clear enough to get a good answer.  It might help to have a diagram showing IP addresses and eth interfaces.